# MySQL Foreign Key Can't create table error:121

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `patient_doctor_decision` (
  `id` bigint(50) NOT NULL,
  `help_entity_id` bigint(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `help_entity` (
  `id` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Both tables already have a lot of data.

I want to establish a FK relationship on patient_doctor_decision.help_entity_id field with help_entity.id field.

```
ALTER TABLE `patient_doctor_decision`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_help_entity` FOREIGN KEY (`help_entity_id`) REFERENCES `help_entity`(`id`);
```

I've verified that foreign keys are valid and there is no foreign key which is not present in the referenced table as primary key.

```
SELECT * FROM patient_doctor_decision d WHERE d.help_entity_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM help_entity);
```

0 rows are returned.

But when I execute the Alter statement mentioned above, I get this error

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-57c_9' (errno: 121)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Are both tables `InnoDB`?

Comment: There's not already an `fk_help_entity` in the table?

Comment: Isn't it because you are using NOT IN?

Comment: Can i know after established relationship which type of result you wanted ?

Comment: it works when i tried to paste your code on the fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f16de

Comment: @ExplosionPills Not exactly, but as I changed the name of foreign key constraint, it started working. The strange thing is that mysql client doesn't show any foreign key with this name. But I'm happy! change of name worked. Thanks for your hint

Comment: Cann't comment answer, I think the problem could be has duplicated constraint_name in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't got the exact thing working but changing the foreign key constraint name worked for me.